# Google Visualization in JQuery Tabs not Displaying in Firefox 3.6.3

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-ui, google-chrome, google-visualization

I seem to have a strange problem. I am working on a simple dashboard that is using JQuery tabs to organize and display Google Visualization graphs. I am using a modified PHP wrapper to generate the JavaScript for the Google Vis side of things. The Google Visualization graph renders correctly in Chrome, Safari, and Safari for the iPad, but not in Firefox 3.6.3. The iFrame that the Google Visualization creates is empty according to firebug, while it is populated and filled according to the Chrome developer tools. Has anyone run into something similar?

Thanks for the help,

Pat

Comment: Are you loading the tabs ajax?

Comment: Yes the tabs are loading via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny I had the same weird issue with two different types of jQuery tabs and Adobes Spry Tabs.

If you have PHP try a simple link like `<a href="?tab=1">Sample Text</a>`. And then a conditional statement like:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['tab'] == "1")
{
print "Your tab content 1 here";
}

if ($_GET['tab'] == "2")
{
print "Your tab content 2 here";
}
?>
ETC...
```

Hope that helps. I tryed everything and it was really bothering me. But BTW if you set a static width it works, I need mine at 100%, but 100px works instead if you have a static page width.